# Remove an association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following associations:

```
class a < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs

class b < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
```

How do I now remove this association? I believe it requires a migration. What should this migration do?

Answer (score 0):

The migration should remove foreign key inside model b. So you need to delete a field called a_id using

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name

remove_column :bs, :a_id
```

See this

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: Thanks, would this automatically remove the index on a_id as well?

Comment: No. There is a remove_index...so before dropping the column first remove the index http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_index

Comment: So, I need to first remove the "belongs_to" declaration in the model file. Then create a migration script to remove the index and the column? No other code needs to be touched?

Comment: When you deploy a new version it will have models without associations. Then you will do bin/rails db:migrate that will remove the columns inside database. You would restart the site and models will have no references and database tables without column and index. The order does not make difference but when you restart you have to run migrations

Comment: Note that this kind of migration is non-reversible. Since you are deleting the data in the column, you will not be able to roll back this change. It is a good practice to either make sure your migrations are reversible (which in simpler cases Rails does on our behalf anyway) or throw `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` from the `down` method.